# Can I use JavaScript to check for installed software on a client machine?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to check the installed software on a client machine using JavaScript?

For example: I want to check on the client machine whether the 'Epson JavaPOS ADK' is installed or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that using Javascript, you don't have access to the local file system.

Comment: Thanks driis for your quick response.

Answer (score 3):

**Impossible**

Due to security issues.

**But** you may still be able to detect any installed software if it installs any browser accessible ActiveX controls. So if you'd try to create an instance of it and see of you actually get an instance of it it has the software. But this is totally software dependent.

Answer (score 2):

That would be extremely dangerous for the client so, no. You can't check nor access the file system. Nor with JavaScript, nor with Java Applets nor with Flash.

Comment: I think with a suitably signed Java applet, you actually can access the filesystem.  That's how online virus scanners such as Trend Micro's Housecall and Kaspersky's Online Scanner work.

Comment: So!! You mean I have to buy a signed JavaScript to achieve this?

Comment: @Garhwali Bhai no. You cannot sign JavaScript. You would need to do it in a Java Applet but due to the nature of your question I seriously doubt that you will be able to get a signed Java Applet so try to work around the problem.